# How to trim the column name of the matrix?

Tags: r

I have matirx, it's column names have two part, I just want to keep the first part.

```
>colnames(mymatrix)

[1] "AF|2312"       "BWDS|54"         "JFD|2111"
```

so I just want to keep part of colnames before `|`

How can I implement it in R ?

Comment: search for `gsub` on Stack Overflow ...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method uses strsplit(), a regex short form for 'everything but letters' to split the vector on, and code to keep only the first part: the letters before the pipe (the negative 2).

```
var  <- c("AF|2312", "BWDS|54", "JFD|2111")

var  <- sapply(strsplit(var, split = "\\W"), "[", -2)

var
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the pipe and everything after it, use

```
colnames(mymatrix) <- gsub("\\|.*","", colnames(mymatrix))
```