# How to edit names using regular expression in R?

Tags: r

I have names like as following. I just want to keep the part before `.` . How

```
>name
    uc001aaa.3
    uc001aac.4
    uc001aae.4
    uc001aah.4
    uc001aai.1
    uc001aak.3
    uc001aal.1
    uc001aam.4
    uc001aaq.2
    uc001aar.2
```

How can I implement this using `regex` or `sub` in R ?

Comment: have you looked at the other `gsub` answers on StackOverflow?

Comment: `gsub("\\.[0-9]$","",name)`

Comment: Why [0-9] ? shouldn't be [0-8] ?  How if the length of name are diffrent ?

Comment: It sounds like you are misunderstanding my answer.  I will post as a real answer, so that I can explain more fully.

Comment: The requested solution is just a degenerate case of the duplicate quickly found with search on: `[r] keep string before`

Comment: `gsub('[.].*', '', nm)` How does this get through and my question gets 3 close votes...haha

Comment: But, when I read my txt. file with read,delim and apply this, I get number, sth maybe go wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought this would certainly be a duplicate, but despite the number of `gsub` question I can't easily find one (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844473/exclude-a-pattern-in-all-collumn-names-in-r).  **Update**: ironically, the closest one is a question the OP asked a few days ago, [How to trim the column name of the matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070172/how-to-trim-the-column-name-of-the-matrix) ...

Anyway,

```
gsub("\\.[0-9]$","",name)
```

does what you want;

- `\\.` specifies a literal `.` character (one backslash is required to specify that `.` is literal rather than meaning "any character"; the second is required to protect the first!). As @MatthewLundberg points out you could also use `[.]` here (`.` is interpreted literally, rather than as "any character", within the range brackets `[]`).
- `[0-9]` means "a single character in the range 0-9" (not, as you seem to think, the first 9 characters of the string)
- `$` means "end of string"

So this will remove a dot plus a single number from the end of every string.  It doesn't matter how many characters are before the dot.  On the other hand, if you might have multiple numeric values, e.g. `foo.123`, you would need `"\\.[0-9]+$` instead (the `+` means "one or more of the preceding pattern")

Comment: I do the following steps :  name<-read.delim("myfile.txt") ; edited<-gsub("\\.[0-9]$","",name), but after doing thism, I get number insted of the name!

Comment: you are reading in a data frame, not a vector.  you either need to use `scan` or use `gsub` on `name$V1`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `strsplit` method, which separates the string on `.` characters, and keeps the first portion:

```
sapply(strsplit(name, '[.]'), '[', 1)
## [1] "uc001aaa" "uc001aac" "uc001aae" "uc001aah" "uc001aai" "uc001aak" "uc001aal" "uc001aam" "uc001aaq" "uc001aar"
```

I'm using the regular expression `[.]` to match a literal dot rather than `\\.` because I find it more readable.  (It also helps if you have multiple levels of interpretation, but that's not an issue here.)